# Rounding to decimal point in jQuery

Tags: jquery, api

I am pulling two objects from a JSON response from `Bing Maps API`, how can I trim loc[0] and loc[1] to 4 decimal places using `jQuery`?

```
var loc = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates;
                $("#resultscoords").html(loc[0] + ',' + loc[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The toFixed function will round to exactly the number you digits you specify, whether there are more or less.

Example

```
n = 1.0;
n.toFixed(2); // Returns 1.00

y = 1.1432176452;
y.toFixed(2); // Returns 1.14
```

In your case, it would be applied the following way:

```
var loc = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates;
$("#resultscoords").html(loc[0].toFixed(4) + ',' + loc[1].toFixed(4));
```

This will return the two results, rounded to four decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

```
var loc = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates;
$("#resultscoords").html(loc[0].toFixed(4) + ',' + loc[1].toFixed(4));
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp